# Spotfire ironPython script change values in table rows

Tags: ironpython, tibco, spotfire

Do you have any idea how can I change values in one column using ironPython script?
I would like to take values from one column in one table (which is easy doable by cursor current value), then 'paste' those values into column in different table. Any ideas?:)

Comment: is there a reason that doing a join via Insert>>Columns... won't solve your issue? or are you specifically looking to automate this using IP?

Comment: unfortunately yes, there is a reason - data in tables are loaded from webservices so they are different through analysis, I'm trying to create a script to create table (after every loading) which will consist of few column (after some transformations like concatenation) from two other tables. I've managed to achieve it through R script, but now I'm trying to 'translate' this to ironPython

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the R script, as well as what you've got in IronPython so far.